# REST SERVICE - Unexpected parameter encountered during deserialization

Tags: rest-api, rest, apexrest, rest-service, httppost

its all perfect! why is this happening? the same endpoint and JSON works in workbench but not in my java code:

REST API :

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/RestTest/*')

global with sharing class restTestShyam {


@HttpPost  
  global static String testRest(String t1, String t2) {
     System.debug('TestVar1: '+T1);
     System.debug('TestVar2: '+T2); 
     //System.debug('TestVar2: '+testVar3);  
    return 'Shyam your test is working';
    }
}
```

My JavaCode to call it:

```
public void restPostExample4() {
    System.out.println("\n_______________ OUTPUT _______________");
    String uri = baseUri + "/services/apexrest/RestTest";
    try {
        // create the JSON object containing the new contact details.
        JSONObject applicant = new JSONObject();
        applicant.put("t1", "shyam");
        applicant.put("t2", "raju");
        System.out.println("JSON for retriving record from test:\n" + applicant.toString(1));

        // Construct the objects needed for the request
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(uri);
        httpPost.addHeader(oauthHeader);
        httpPost.addHeader(prettyPrintHeader);
        // The message we are going to post
        StringEntity body = new StringEntity(applicant.toString(1));
        body.setContentType("application/json");
        httpPost.setEntity(body);

        // Make the request
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

        // Process the results
        int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        if (statusCode == 201 || statusCode == 200) {
            String response_string = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response_string);
            System.out.println("Retrive Successful! Status code returned is " + statusCode);
            System.out.println("Response from RestTest: " + json);
            System.out.println("httpPOST: " + httpPost);
            // Store the retrieved data as follows.
            // eg.....
            // contactId = json.getString("id");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Retrive unsuccessful. Status code returned is " + statusCode);
            System.out.println(getBody(response.getEntity().getContent()));
            System.out.println("httpPOST: " + httpPost);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        System.out.println("Issue creating JSON or processing results");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NullPointerException npe) {
        npe.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

My Output:

_______________ OUTPUT _______________

```
JSON for retriving record on applicant from yesterday:
{
 "t1": "shyam",
 "t2": "raju"
}
Retrive unsuccessful. Status code returned is 400
[ {
  "message" : "Unexpected parameter encountered during deserialization: t1 at [line:2, column:9]",
  "errorCode" : "JSON_PARSER_ERROR"
} ]

httpPOST: POST https://XX.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/XX/v37.0/services/apexrest/RestTest HTTP/1.1
Program complete.
```

workbench output:

[image]

PLEASE let me know what the problem is thanks! is it in my java code? or my apex class? but how is the same json i make as output running on workbench but not through java, im using the access token in the header and my login is successful so please dont tell me thats why...thanks guys really appreciate it!

SFDC error log:

```
39.0 APEX_CODE,FINER;APEX_PROFILING,NONE;CALLOUT,NONE;DB,INFO;SYSTEM,DEBUG;VALIDATION,NONE;VISUALFORCE,FINER;WAVE,INFO;WORKFLOW,FINER
17:44:40.0 (439003)|USER_INFO|[EXTERNAL]|asajshahjad|--------|Central Standard Time|GMT-06:00
17:44:40.0 (464306)|EXECUTION_STARTED
17:44:40.0 (468050)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|01p210000009mIA|OutREST.OutREST
17:44:40.0 (635706)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[72]|Bytes:3
17:44:40.0 (678017)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[77]|Bytes:152
17:44:40.0 (692694)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[342]|Bytes:408
17:44:40.0 (710332)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[355]|Bytes:408
17:44:40.0 (726966)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[467]|Bytes:48
17:44:40.0 (751711)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[139]|Bytes:6
17:44:40.0 (792234)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:252
17:44:40.0 (796299)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:25
17:44:40.0 (807616)|SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[1]|RestRequest.RestRequest()
17:44:40.0 (811516)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[1]
17:44:40.0 (820119)|SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[1]|RestRequest
17:44:40.0 (826856)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:32
17:44:40.0 (845941)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:8
17:44:40.0 (848114)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:24
17:44:40.0 (1180053)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:32
17:44:40.0 (1184520)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:13
17:44:40.0 (1185920)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:1
17:44:40.0 (1252081)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:32
17:44:40.0 (1255059)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:11
17:44:40.0 (1256360)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:44
17:44:40.0 (1282295)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:32
17:44:40.0 (1284585)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:10
17:44:40.0 (1285909)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:10
17:44:40.0 (1307325)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:32
17:44:40.0 (1309623)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:10
17:44:40.0 (1310864)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:40
17:44:40.0 (1331573)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:32
17:44:40.0 (1333825)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:4
17:44:40.0 (1335128)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:19
17:44:40.0 (1355759)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:32
17:44:40.0 (1357945)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:16
17:44:40.0 (1359225)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:12
17:44:40.0 (1379604)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:32
17:44:40.0 (1381767)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:12
17:44:40.0 (1383102)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:16
17:44:40.0 (1437991)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:156
17:44:40.0 (1441627)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:10
17:44:40.0 (1448782)|SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[1]|RestResponse.RestResponse()
17:44:40.0 (1451342)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[1]
17:44:40.0 (1456238)|SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[1]|RestResponse
17:44:40.0 (1460351)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:16
17:44:40.0 (1548789)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:112
17:44:40.0 (1552754)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:5
17:44:40.0 (1559294)|SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[2]|RestContext.RestContext()
17:44:40.0 (1561352)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[2]
17:44:40.0 (1565730)|SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[2]|RestContext
17:44:40.0 (1570102)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:32
17:44:40.0 (1579298)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:16
17:44:40.0 (3255271)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|OutREST.OutREST
17:44:40.0 (6483214)|EXECUTION_FINISHED
```

Comment: Workbench works, so it means there is something wrong in your Java code. I am not familiar with Java, but wondering if `applicant.toString(1)` should be `applicant.toString()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This certainly looks like a problem in your JSON serialization implementation in your Java program .

Assuming you are using JSON.simple imports like below

```
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
```

The proper way to convert to JSON string would below

```
 StringEntity body = new StringEntity(applicant.toJSONString());
```

Alternatively use [Jackson](http://www.mkyong.com/java/jackson-2-convert-java-object-to-from-json/) for faster JSON to string serializer

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53581/discussion-on-answer-by-mohith-shrivastava-rest-service-unexpected-parameter-e).